# get multi data atrributes from element classes of response html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

how to get muttiple data attribute from element classes of response html.
I can extract only data.

this is response.html

```html
<div class="book" data-name="frozen" data-author="micheal" data-price="30">
  Frozen
</div>
<div class="book" data-name="unbroken" data-author="jimmy" data-price="25">
  Unbroken
</div>
<div class="book" data-name="carry on" data-author="alex" data-price="32">
  Carry On
</div>
```

Ajax code here

```
 function getData($scope){
        $.ajax({  

        url: "/response.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
          var $response = $(response);
          // not working
          // var $book-data = $response.find('div.book').data({'name','author','price'});
          var $bookData = $response.find('div.book').data('name');
          alert($bookData);
          }          
        });
      }
```

I wish to get book-data as json or array to display in angular.

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, thank for your response. This code tested and worked. I am so naive so I don't get what you point out "attempt".

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, I didn't add alert($book-data), but I just did. Because it is testing stage. What I want to complete is to return book-data json or array. It is just testing. alert box will appear if this code run. No syntaxError: missing;

Comment: Sorry @JaromandaX I just use $book in my code. I described as $book-data because I wish to describe what I want clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var bookData=Array();
$.get("stackTest.html", function(response) {
    $.each($(response).find(".book"),function(ind,ele){
        bookData.push($(ele).data());

    });
  console.log(bookData);
});
```

then you get an array with the data-object of each ".book" node

mike

Comment: Hi @Mike, Thank, your solution is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy:

```js
var allData = [];
$('.book').each(function(i){
 allData.push( $(this).data() );
});
console.log( allData );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book" data-name="frozen" data-author="micheal" data-price="30">
    Frozen
</div>
<div class="book" data-name="unbroken" data-author="jimmy" data-price="25">
    Unbroken
</div>
<div class="book" data-name="carry on" data-author="alex" data-price="32">
    Carry On
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @skobaljic. Thank for your help. but how to search in $response. I can't `call $('.book').each()`. Sorry. I am just junior amateur. :-P

Comment: Got it. Same as what I did. 
` success: function(response) {
              var $response = $(response);
              var allData = [];
              $response.find('div.book').each(function(i){
                allData.push( $(this).data() );
              });
              console.log( allData );
              } 
`

Comment: Can't say I did not expect the reward. By the way, `The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object`, take a look in [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: Hi @skobaljic, I really sorry for you. I am just a beginner level developer. I can't decide which one better. :-( But I hope your selector.each is more specific. And you helped me with a correct one too.